# Esperar respuesta de readline en un loop en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, terminal, asincronismo

Pido ayuda para resolver una duda en el lenguaje JavaScript, vengo del lenguaje Java y estoy un poco confundido con el asincronismo y tiempos de respuesta.

Lo que qiero hacer (hecho en java);

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList jugadores = new ArrayList();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del jugador");
        String nombre = scanner.nextLine();
        jugadores.add(nombre);
    }

    System.out.println("Jugadores\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(jugadores.get(i));
    }
}
```

}

terminal output:

```
Jugador1
Jugador2 
Jugador3
Jugador4
Jugador5
```

Lo que tengo (hecho en javascript):

```
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
 input: process.stdin,
 output: process.stdout,
});

let jugadores = [];

function scanner(arg) {
  readline.question(arg, (response) => {
    readline.close();
    return response;
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let nombre = scanner("Ingrese el nombre del jugador\n");
  jugadores.push(nombre);
}

for (let k = 0; k < jugadores.length; k++) {
  console.log(jugadores[k]);
}
```

Quiero poder ingresar cada jugador y luego me los muestre, sin embargo mi codigo no funciona, me pide el nombre del jugador al mismo tiempo que imprime todos los jugadores que tengo, quisiera que el metodo fuera async pero no tengo idea como implementarlo.

terminal output:

```
Ingrese el nombre del jugador
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

El asunto de obtener datos desde consola se vuelve un tanto difícil al momento de necesitar un loop debido a temas relacionados con la asincronía por ponerlo de una manera fácil (puedes obtener un mejor panorama en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24466103/7927192) en el sitio en inglés). En pocas palabras no puedes hacer la siguiente pregunta sin antes haber tratado la respuesta de la pregunta anterior.

Por lo que una de las opciones que tienes es utilizar recursividad y hacer todo el procedimiento dentro del mismo lugar.

```javascript
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const jugadores = [];

function obtenerJugadores(totalJugadores) {
  rl.question("Nombre del jugador: ", function (line) {
    if (totalJugadores === 1) {
      jugadores.push(line);
      jugadores.forEach((jugador, i) => {
        console.log(`Jugador[${i + 1}]: ${jugador}`);
      });
      return rl.close();
    }
    jugadores.push(line);
    obtenerJugadores(totalJugadores - 1);
  });
};

obtenerJugadores(5);
```

Con lo anterior tendrás algo similar a la siguiente *interacción* con la consola:

```
Nombre del jugador: Ana
Ana
Nombre del jugador: Juan
Juan
Nombre del jugador: José
José
Nombre del jugador: Marcos
Marcos
Nombre del jugador: Pedro
Pedro
Jugador[1]: Ana
Jugador[2]: Juan
Jugador[3]: José
Jugador[4]: Marcos
Jugador[5]: Pedro
```

Otra opción que puede ser un poco menos rebuscada, es hacer una función que devuelva una promesa como respuesta, así podemos mantener un poco la estructura original que planteas:

```javascript
const readline = require('readline');

function scanner(ask) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(ask, (input) => {rl.close(); resolve(input)});
  });
}

async function obtenerJugadores(totalJugadores) {
  const jugadores = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < totalJugadores; i++) {
    const jugador = await scanner('Nombre del jugador: ');
    jugadores.push(jugador);
  }

  jugadores.forEach((jugador, i) => {
    console.log(`Jugador[${i + 1}]: ${jugador}`);
  });
}

obtenerJugadores(5);
```

Cuyo resultado es similar al de la primera implementación:

```
Nombre del jugador: Ramiro
Ramiro
Nombre del jugador: Juan
Juan
Nombre del jugador: Marcos
Marcos
Nombre del jugador: María
María
Nombre del jugador: Sol
Sol
Jugador[1]: Ramiro
Jugador[2]: Juan
Jugador[3]: Marcos
Jugador[4]: María
Jugador[5]: Sol
```

Lo anterior se podría decir que es una implementación básica del paquete [`readline-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-promise).

Comment: Como me recomiendas manejar esto si tengo que implementar la funcion asyncrona dentro de un while? 

algo como:

while(true){
obtenerJugadores(2);
}

Comment: Depende de dónde necesites implementar el `while`, pues por lo que entiendo necesitas reemplazar el `for` por un `while`. Entonces esa estructura de control podría estar implementada dentro de la función `obtenerJugadores()` para reemplazar la forma que está implementada ahora mismo.